# disabling PowerPoint's "automatic centering"

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When I design charts in PowerPoint, I sometimes need to typographically fine tune the text boxes of data values, where I have to zoom all the way in to see them.  Inevitably, PowerPoint will automatically animatedly shift the viewport to the center of the chart, bringing what I need to look at completely out of view.  Is there any way of suppressing this monstrous "feature"?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround:

Design your graph in Excel, copy and paste. You must save the Excel worksheet into the same folder as your PPT work and have Excel available if you want to make changes as you edit your PPT work. If you move your PPT work file, you should move the Excel worksheet, too. Otherwise it easily will get lost.

If you have moved the files and want to edit the graph data, you must Update the link manually. Fortunately it's made easy.

Even the link problem has a workaround. Have a special dia at the end of your presentation that contains your Excel worksheet as an object. Copy and paste the graph to your presentation from that worksheet. On the Excel worksheet no autocentering occurs. Unfortunately you can edit the graph data only in that special dia and you must copy and repaste the edited graph. This makes the editing clunky, so avoid the last workaround.